# ゲストOS上でマウスカーソルが表示されず、ホストOSとのコピペやドラッグ＆ドロップができない

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Windows 10 + VirtualBox 6.1 + CentOS 7

なのですが、ゲストOSのCentOS上でマウスカーソルが消えてしまい、コピペやドラッグ＆ドロップなどができません。（ゲストOSの画面上で、マウス操作が一切できない）

ゲストOSの画面をクリックすると、カーソルが消えて入力（リナックスコマンドなど）はでき、右側のctrlを押すと、ホストOS側でマウスカーソルが表示され、通常通りWindowsの操作はできます。

ゲストOS上で `modelinfo vboxguest` をやってみた結果を以下に抜粋しますと、

```
 version 6.1.14 r140239
 description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
```

が出てくるので、インストールはされていると思います。

他には以下の記事の内容を試しましたが、改善しませんでした。

[VirtualBox 6.0で作成した仮想マシンにCentOSをインストールしようとするとマウスカーソルが表示されない問題への対処 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/keicha_hrs/items/704d200cd9c98a4b2f71)

他に何か原因があるのでしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

(追記)
画面については以下のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `Guest Additions`が新しい(6.1.4)とダメで6.1.2に落としたという記事があるようですが。[VirtualBoxでクリップボードの共有ができない](https://qiita.com/pldb/items/197811e7655c5e779617)

Comment: OS のインストールは問題無かったのでしょうか？ / ゲストOSがテキストモードで起動しているということはありませんか？どんな画面になっているのかを貼り付けてもらうと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ゲストOSを起動した後、初めからこの黒い画面が表示されますか？それともWindowsのようなGUIでユーザー名とパスワードを入力する画面が表示されますか？

Comment: 返信が遅くなりすみません。
最初から黒画面で、GUI（グラフィック）の画面は一度も表示されません。

Comment: 前述の通りテキストモードでOSが起動しているため、マウスが使えない状態です。 / どの様にインストールされたのか分かりませんが、`startx` コマンドを実行して GUI モードに移行するかを試してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。解決しました。startxをやってみたら使えなかったのですが、GNOMEが入っていないことが原因だったようで、インストールしたら解決しました。

Comment: コメントでのやり取りを踏まえて、解決に至った情報 (何が原因で、どうしたら解決したか) といったところを自己回答の形で投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

コメントのやり取りを踏まえて回答としてまとめておきます。

---

質問に貼られた画面を見る限り、OSが (マウスを使わず文字入力を中心に操作を行う) **コマンドモード** で起動しているのが原因です。

どのように CentOS をインストールしたのかが分かりませんが、`startx` と実行してグラフィカルモードに移行するか、GNOME や KDE などのデスクトップ環境をインストールしてみてください。